# converting string to long in python

Tags: python

Python provides a convenient method long() to convert string to long:

```
long('234')
```

; converts '234' into a long

If user keys in 234.89 then python will raise an error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long()
with base 10: '234.89'
```

How should we a python programmer handles scenarios where a string with a decimal value ?

Thank you =)

Comment: convert it to float?  Catch the error and report to the user?

Comment: This question and its answers only apply to Python 2.  Python 3 no longer has a long type, see http://python3porting.com/differences.html#long

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`long`can only take string convertibles which can end in a base 10 numeral. So, the decimal is causing the harm. What you can do is, `float` the value before calling the `long`. If your program is on Python 2.x where int and long difference matters, and you are sure you are not using large integers, you could have just been fine with using `int` to provide the key as well.

So, the answer is `long(float('234.89'))` or it could just be `int(float('234.89'))` if you are not using large integers. Also note that this difference does not arise in Python 3, because int is upgraded to long by default. All integers are long in python3 and call to covert is just `int`

Comment: int('234.89') fails with the same error as shown in the question.

Comment: @payne- thanks for point out. I have corrected it. Your's was correct.

Answer (score 17):

Well, longs can't hold anything but integers.

One option is to use a float:  `float('234.89')`

The other option is to truncate or round.  Converting from a float to a long will truncate for you:  `long(float('234.89'))`

```
>>> long(float('1.1'))
1L
>>> long(float('1.9'))
1L
>>> long(round(float('1.1')))
1L
>>> long(round(float('1.9')))
2L
```